# Angular : prevent api error to not display HTML template

Tags: angular, api, templates, handle

When I do HTTP requests, for example a GET request and that i got a status code 400 for invalid given data, it prevents my HTML template to be displayed in the view of my angular app.
This is how I deal with it at the moment :

```
this.myService.getData(neededData)
  .subscribe(
    (result) => {
      this.data = result;
    },
    (error) => { 
      if (error) { 
        console.log("error"); 
        this.anErrorHasOccured = true; 
      }
    }
  );
```

The 'error' is well displayed in the console, but this error prevents my template to be displayed, how can I fix that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try with this :

```js
this.myService.getData(neededData)
  .pipe(catchError(err => {
    console.err(err);
    return of([]);
  }))
  .subscribe(
    (result) => this.data = result,
  );
```

Comment: thx for helping me, this is the error i got from VScode with this code : `Argument of type '(err: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<Object>) => ObservableInput<any>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'.`

Comment: import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

Comment: You have correclty imported { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators'; ?

Comment: Yeeaah great ! :D